# Android Facebook login callbacks never fire

Tags: java, android, facebook-login, android-facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I created an activity with facebook login button and registered callbacks in onCreate method. Now when I press login button and login through facebook I expect my callbacks to be fired but they don't. What am I doing wrong?

```
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    LoginButton loginButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancelled!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Does the Facebook activity get started ? You need to add it to your manifest and also check the `onActivityResult` method !

Comment: Yes, I see facebook window where I give my app permissions. What should I add to `onActivityResult`?

Comment: @LeonardoFerrari omg I am retarded. Thank you. It works now.

Comment: No problem ! Post your solution as an answer, so you can help other people in the future !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are posting code for callbacks not working.

1. I am assuming that you have created a project on facebook developer console, obtained development hashes and status is set to public.
2. Your application manifest has meta-data tag for application id.

**So further coming to your code, add onActivityResult() in your activity and forward it to your callbackManager.** ([Facebook Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3))

If login succeeds, the LoginResult parameter has the new AccessToken, and the most recently granted or declined permissions.

You don't need a registerCallback for login to succeed, you can choose to follow current access token changes with the AccessTokenTracker class described below.

Then in onActivityResult() forward the login results to the callbackManager created in onCreate():

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. Please check if you have added the following in your manifest file:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And the following in your strings.xml:

```
<string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme">fbAPP_ID</string>
```

Please note in the above line, your app ID should be preceeded by "fb". This is clearly mentioned in the Facebook docs and I had failed to notice this minute detail.
If your App ID is 1234567, you should use fb1234567
However when you are calling  FacebookSdk.setApplicationId(), you need not prefix fb.
Ref:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android